why i can't adjust my window size or move firefox in kali
I just opened up my pc, only to find i cannot adjust firefox window, my terminal is displayed at the bottom and it cannot move either. I typed in the following command based on the following solution and it worked xfwm4. My question is what could be the problem that led to these behavior.
